# How to use string.Format with curly brackets

Tags: c#, json, string, serialization, string.format

I want to create a json string that contains a list of long values with the following structure:
{"document_ids":[23461504,20639162,20395579]}

I solved the problem with the line below, but I feel like I could do it with a cleaner command(string.Format).

```
var json = "{\"document_ids\":" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(My List<long>) + "}";
```

But the command I write with string.Format gives an error message.

```
var json = string.Format("{\"document_ids\":{0}}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(My List<long>));
```

I get this error message.
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: did you try `var json = string.Format("{\"document_ids\":{0}}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList));`

Comment: Yes, I did But it gave error

Comment: Why are you trying to construct a full JSON object yourself? The built-in JSON classes and [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) both provide excellent ways of serialising and deserialising JSON objects for you. Doing it manually can introduce a lot of bugs and undesired behaviours down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialize an anonymous object having such a `document_ids` property.

```
var numbers = new List<long> { 23461504, 20639162, 20395579 };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        document_ids = numbers
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not manually assemble json strings. There are already useful classes that make the most work for you. Just use the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` class for example.

A full working example would be this:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var myData = new MyData()
        {
            MyListOfLongs = new List<long>() { 23461504, 20639162, 20395579 }
        };

        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize( myData, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true } );
    }
}

public class MyData
{
    [JsonPropertyName( "document_ids" )]
    public List<long> MyListOfLongs
    { get; set; }
}
```

The variable `jsonString` contains your desired json string ^^

If you like to deserialize the string again, take a look at the class `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` again ... it contains also a `Deserialize` method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is correct but I can't give you Upvote.